# How to access values from an Arraylist containing an array?

Tags: c#, arraylist, foreach

Instead to read all the rows contained in a datagridview, I wanted to experiment the use of the arraylist, hope it's faster (is it?).

So, I have GridRows in an arraylist, and each "rows" is containing GridColumns also as array, here's my code to populate the list (test only).

Question : I wonder how to get in a loop each gridRows and to get the 2 values (string) from the gridColumns ?

Adding values to my list (example) :

```
        var MyDataGrid = new List<GridRows>();
        int rowindex;

        rowindex = 1;
        MyDataGrid.Add(new GridRows(rowindex, new List<GridColumns>
    {
        new GridColumns { Name = "Column2", Value = "LO016" },
        new GridColumns { Name = "Column3", Value = "NewLO016" },
        new GridColumns { Name = "Column4", Value = "7.09" },
        new GridColumns { Name = "Column5", Value = "Test2" },
        new GridColumns { Name = "StatusColumn", Value = "Redacted" }
    }));

        rowindex = 2;
        MyDataGrid.Add(new GridRows(rowindex, new List<GridColumns>
    {
        new GridColumns { Name = "Column2", Value = "LO017" },
        new GridColumns { Name = "Column3", Value = "NewLO017" },
        new GridColumns { Name = "Column4", Value = "14.1" },
        new GridColumns { Name = "Column5", Value = "Test3" },
        new GridColumns { Name = "StatusColumn", Value = "Rejected" }
    }));
```

thanks :)

Comment: Are you sure `GridRows` is an `ArrayList`? It seems to be its own type? Do you mean its derived from `ArrayList`? Can you show the type definitions?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried Dictionary? - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-6.0

```
var MyDataGrid = new Dictionary<int,List<GridColumns>>();
var allColumns = MyDataGrid.Values ;
```

here allColumns is list of List.

If you need all GridColumns from MyDataGrid in list.

```
allGridColumns = MyDataGrid.Values.SelectMany(x=>x);
```

if you have hashed data like you mentioned, dictionary works faster and has built in methods.

*Wrote this code directly, may contain minor syntax errors.